# Why is it not printing the entire list?

Tags: prolog

I want to print all members of list L, but it just prints the first member.

```
user_friends_of_friends(Name,L):-
        user(ID,Name),
        findall(X,(be_friends(ID,X)),L),
        member(T,L),
        write(T).
```

What am I doing wrong with this prolog code?

Comment: Try changing the last line to this: `write(T), fail.`. Does that work?

Comment: Can skip `findall/3` and `member/2` also (but add `; true` at the end).

Comment: Remove `member(T,L), write(T)` and use `write(L)`. But that will be somewhat redundant since Prolog is going to write to the terminal what `L` is after your query anyway. So you could skip using `write(L)`.